# mysql data being displayed multiple times

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I am trying to fetch details from a mysql table and display it using ajax.
I have been successful in showing my records but it seems the records are being displayed in a loop.
For ex: Numbers from 1 to 10 are being displayed and as soon as the list of 10 is completed, again numbers from 1 to 10 are being displayed.
I cant find where I am going wrong.

Javascript

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function(){
    setInterval(function(){
        $.ajax({
            url: 'details.php',
            success: function(data){
                var response=JSON.parse(data);
                var no=1;

                $(function(){
                    $.each(response, function(i, item){
                        var change = no % 2;
                        if(change === 0){
                            $('<tr>').append(
                                $('<td>').text(item.memo).addClass('table1'),
                                $('<td>').text(item.pid).addClass('table1'),
                                $('<td>').text(item.qty).addClass('table1'),
                                $('<td>').text(item.amt).addClass('table1')
                            ).appendTo('#Table1');
                        }
                        else{
                            $('<tr>').append(
                                $('<td>').text(item.memo).addClass('table2'),
                                $('<td>').text(item.pid).addClass('table2'),
                                $('<td>').text(item.qty).addClass('table2'),
                                $('<td>').text(item.amt).addClass('table2')
                            ).appendTo('#Table1');
                        }
                        no = no+1;
                    });
                });
            }
        });
    }, 1000);
});
</script>
```

PHP

```
<?php
include 'connect.php';
$timestamp = "";
$return = array();
$response = "";
$sql = "SELECT * FROM receipts ORDER BY timestamp DESC LIMIT 1";
$result1 = mysqli_query($db, $sql);
if($details = mysqli_fetch_array($result1)){
    $timestamp = $details['timestamp'];
}

$sql = "SELECT * FROM sales WHERE timestamp>'$timestamp'";
$result = mysqli_query($db, $sql);
while($fetch_options=mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
    $return[]=array('memo'=>$fetch_options['memo'], 'pid'=>$fetch_options['pid'], 'qty'=>$fetch_options['qty'], 'amt'=>$fetch_options['amt']);
}
$response = $return;
echo json_encode($response);
?>
```

HTML

```
     <table width="300" id="Table1" name="Table1">
     <tr>
        <th width="68" id="wb_uid0"><div class="CustomStyle"><span id="wb_uid1"><strong> Memo</strong></span></div>
        </th>
        <th width="64" id="wb_uid2"><div><span id="wb_uid3"><strong> Product ID</strong></span></div>
        </th>
        <th width="50" id="wb_uid4"><div><span id="wb_uid5"><strong> Qty</strong></span></div>
        </th>
        <th width="88" id="wb_uid6"><div><span id="wb_uid7"><strong> Amount</strong></span></div>
        </th>
     </tr>
     </table>
```

Comment: Not related to the problem, but you don't need to use `$(function()...)` in the callback.

Comment: You're using `setInterval`, which runs the function every second.

Comment: isn't it because of `setInterval`?

Comment: Sounds like you just need to empty the table before you append the new rows each time.

Comment: I would like to update the table each second. What should I do?

Comment: can you check my edited answer? I think its helpful to you.

Answer (score 0):

you can try like this

change JS

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function(){
     setInterval(function(){
    $.ajax({
        url: 'details.php',
        success: function(data){

            $('#Table1').find('#appendRow').remove();
            var response=JSON.parse(data);
            var no=1;

                $.each(response, function(i, item){
                    var change = no % 2;
                    if(change === 0){
                        $('<tr id="appendRow">').append(
                            $('<td>').text(item.memo).addClass('table1'),
                            $('<td>').text(item.pid).addClass('table1'),
                            $('<td>').text(item.qty).addClass('table1'),
                            $('<td>').text(item.amt).addClass('table1')
                        ).appendTo('#Table1');
                    }
                    else{
                        $('<tr id="appendRow">').append(
                            $('<td>').text(item.memo).addClass('table2'),
                            $('<td>').text(item.pid).addClass('table2'),
                            $('<td>').text(item.qty).addClass('table2'),
                            $('<td>').text(item.amt).addClass('table2')
                        ).appendTo('#Table1');
                    }
                    no = no+1;
            });
        }
    });
}, 1000);
});
</script>
```

I am not sure but i think it's helpful to you.

Comment: I have a table set in my html with only the headers. According to your code the headers get removed.

Comment: Ok..the display now works file but now each second a tr gets removed from top and another gets added below.

Comment: yeah. it's your requirement. right? If you don't want to remove `tr` then you get only new record not a repeated records. If you get new records, so you have no requirement to remove `tr`.

Comment: My requirement is to update the table each second without compromising the css setup. Plus I dont want the user to have a continuous distraction of the table being updated which is happening in this case as the list continuously keeps scrolling up.

Answer (score 0):

the previous answer is correct the problem is this line:
 **$('#Table1').children().remove();**
which removes all table children including the headers. which is why they are missing when you append content.

**EDIT**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function(){
     setInterval(function(){
    $.ajax({
        url: 'details.php',
        success: function(data){

            var response=JSON.parse(data);
            var no=1;
                $('.removable').remove();
                $.each(response, function(i, item){
                    var change = no % 2;
                    if(change === 0){
                        $('<tr class="removable">').append(
                            $('<td>').text(item.memo).addClass('table1'),
                            $('<td>').text(item.pid).addClass('table1'),
                            $('<td>').text(item.qty).addClass('table1'),
                            $('<td>').text(item.amt).addClass('table1')
                        ).appendTo('#Table1');
                    }
                    else{
                        $('<tr class="removable">').append(
                            $('<td>').text(item.memo).addClass('table2'),
                            $('<td>').text(item.pid).addClass('table2'),
                            $('<td>').text(item.qty).addClass('table2'),
                            $('<td>').text(item.amt).addClass('table2')
                        ).appendTo('#Table1');
                    }
                    no = no+1;
            });
        }
    });
}, 1000);
});
</script>
```

This should work let me know if i missed something.

make sure to add the 'removable' class to the corresponding "tr" in your HTML.

Comment: Can you help me with the line??

Comment: the easiest thing would be to append the headers before you call "each" function.

Comment: An example would be helpful. If I append the headets before each function then I need to set a css for it right? Because the existing css wont work.  Am I right?? Can I use innerhtml instead of appending the headers?

Comment: use css selectors to add desired css to headers then just append existing html code. i edited my post to give you an example.

Comment: Can you put the above code in the required place because I am having a bit difficulty in doing.